# How to make Typescript detect import path error with a case sensitive typo?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, import, eslint

Typescript didn't detect this typo error (case sensitive).

The name of the file: `AdminTextArea`

The import with the typo `import AdminTextArea from "@components/AdminTextarea"`

The typo is: `area` instead of the correct word `Area`.

My Typescript environment didn't complain about this at all.

[image]

No errors are shown and it runs smoothly.

It was only after I've transpiled it to JS with babel and sent it to run on my Docker container on the cloud, that it triggered this error:

[image]

The path is perfect, except for the typo.

What can I do to detect this error in my dev Typescript environment? Is this an `eslint` thing or is my Typescript not configured correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is operating-system dependent. Some operating systems have a case-insensitive file system (MacOS would be the primary example). Linux file systems are case-sensitive, so this error may manifest when moving from a case-insensitive file system to one that is case-sensitive.

Unfortunately, TypeScript can't do much about this since it depends on the file system itself. You can add this compiler setting:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
```

This may help detect this error.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I'm asking myself **how is this not enabled by default!**?

Answer (score 2):

With ESLint rule [import/no-unresolved](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md#casesensitive) you can make sure that case sensitive imports are added correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure people will still have this error and this is how I fixed it on my side, has worked in 3 different scenarios.

Let's say you have the file `AdminTextarea.js` which is renamed to `AdminTextArea.js`. Since MacOS by default does case-insensitive file handling, this issue is going to be predominant there.

#### Steps to fix this

- Rename the problem file to an obscure name, so `AdminTextarea.js` -> `MYNAMEISJEFF.js` (be different from the original file name, don't use adminTextArea of some other combination)
- Update all places where this file was used. (VS code has support for doing this)
- Once all imports have been updated, rename the file to whatever the desired name is, in this case `AdminTextArea.js`. Update all imports again, and viòla, the problem has been fixed.

#### How to avoid this problem in the future

Stick to standard camelCase or snake_case file naming conventions and prevent changing the filename differing in only the case

Lmk if this helps, it's been working for me!